# Which program (hex editor) can convert from hex code string to unicode?

Tags: unicode

Suppose I have string, returned in Json, like

```
004100610061
```

Is is string. But if interpreted as Hex, and then as Unicode, this will mean

```
Aaa
```

Which hex editor can provide ability to decode this?

With Bless I was able to paste hex, but does not able to see Unicode.

Comment: There will be a headache here.  It matters what encoding the original string was used.  If you are unsure what encoding it is using, then you will get multiple possible results.

Comment: Also, are you absolutely certain the hex string there is actually meant to represent a printable string, and not something that can only be interpreted by whatever created the JSON?

Comment: In addition to what Thomas asked, what is the desired _output_ encoding, i.e. the encoding of the resulting file? UTF-8?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use xxd.  For example:

```
xxd -r -p <(echo 004100610061)
```

Of course that wont put in an extra new line so you might want to immediately invoke echo, too, for example:

```
xxd -r -p <(echo 004100610061) ; echo
```

Then again, maybe the crazy redirection makes those commands confusing, so perhaps it might be easier to follow what it does this way:

```
echo 004100610061 | xxd -r -p ; echo
```

xxd reads the input from echo and -r says to go from a hex dump back to binary, and the -p says forget about looking for address info in the hex dump, and then the echo inserts an extra new line.  So these commands are all just xxd reading its input from standard in, converting the hex values back into binary, and then displaying them.

Edit:
As @Rudd points out, this will just be binary output.  Your terminal will probably ignore the non-printable bits and stupidly interpret it as ascii, so stick some extra bytes on there and redirect your output to a file for a more accurate conversion.

For example, if you know your input is big endian utf-16:

```
echo feff004100610061 | xxd -r -p > output.txt
```

Then view the result in a unicode-aware editor.

For example:

```
vim output.txt
```

For other encoding BOMs, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding)

Comment: Not immediately visible on most terminals: each letter is preceded by a NUL character. What's worse, non-ASCII characters will be mangled. I guess xxd does not care about encoding; it just outputs one byte for each 2 hex digits in the input.

Comment: Some terminals *might* be smart enough to just display the text, you could try yours and see.  For example, gnome-terminal seems to be doing big endian utf-8 with no problem, the BOM for that is efbbbf, so try this:

    echo efbbbf004100610061 | xxd -r -p

But then, maybe it's just discarding characters it can't display...

Comment: Thanks for the edit concerning UTF-16 with BOM. I wasn't aware vim (different from most other GNU tools) could handle UTF-16; works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can withdraw from installing additional soft and use Vi/Vim editor which is integrated in any Linux distribution.

Vi substitute (`:s`)command allows doing this via following pattern:

```
 :%s/\(\x\{4\}\)/\=nr2char('0x'.submatch(1),1)/g
```

Simple `:s` replace only the current line whereas `:%s` replaces codes in all lines.
There are couple of other ways to simplify Unicode representation in Vim but they require plugins or setting digraphs.

**Note:** for the above implementation you need full-featured VIM, but not VIM-tiny.
The `nr2char` parameter is valid only from version 7.4, if you have lower version of VIM you can put this parameter aside which shouldn't affect functionality in any way.

Comment: Works fine in VIM 7.3 (Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS), but I had to remove the second parameter of `nr2char` or it would give an error. Could not get it to work on VIM 7.4 (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS); the command just cleared the line. I did not test version 8 of VIM; hopefully that works.

Comment: @Ruud, works wonderfully on my VIM 7.4 without removing any parameters. Seek the problem elsewhere.

Comment: Your command is fine, but it has two important requirements that are worth mentioning. (1) Needs full-blown vim, _not_ vim-tiny. The latter was installed by default when I started using Ubuntu years ago. Sorry, I was never aware of that. (2) Needs version 7.4; the `utf8` parameter of `nr2char` did not exist in 7.3. But like I said, it appears to work fine without the extra parameter; tested with some characters outside the ASCII range.

Comment: @Ruud, thanks for review. Added this info to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

```
echo 004100610061 | perl -CS -pe 's/[0-9A-F]{4}/chr(hex($&))/egi'
```

Output:

```
Aaa
```

The command line option `-CS` forces output to be UTF-8 encoded.